# Updating a Rails Association table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

I'm working on a quiz app in Rails that keeps track of a number of **Facts**

app/models/fact.rb

```
class Fact < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates(:question, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false })
    validates(:answer, presence: true)
end
```

Every time a user takes a new quiz, they generate an **Exam**

app/models/exam.rb

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :assign_facts
    belongs_to :user
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    has_many :problems
    has_many :facts, through: :problems

    def assigned?(fact)
        problems.find_by(fact_id: fact.id)
    end

    def assign!(fact)
        problems.create!(fact_id: fact.id)
    end

    private

        def assign_facts
            facts = Fact.all.sample(10)
            facts.each do |fact|
                self.assign!(fact)
            end
        end

end
```

Since there are many Exams all using the same Facts, each Exam `has_many` Facts `though` an association table of **Problems**

app/models/problem.rb:

```
class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :exam
    belongs_to :fact
    validates :exam_id, presence: true
    validates :fact_id, presence: true
end
```

excerpt from db/scheme.rb:

```
  create_table "problems", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "exam_id"
    t.integer  "fact_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "correct",    default: false
  end
```

My problem is that I'm trying to figure out how to store the results of each user's exam (whether they answer a specific question either correctly, or incorrectly). I was planning on updating the association table each time the user answers a question and storing the result in the `t.boolean  "correct"` collumn. This would be a fairly simple matter in PHP/MySQL (`UPDATE problems SET correct = 1 WHERE exam = 'id' AND fact = 'id'`), but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do it the Rails way.

Is there some way I can simply, and easily update my associations table (problems) with Rails? **OR** Should I create a fourth table (maybe 'results' or something) to keep track of the user's correct/incorrect answers? --I know I don't have any controller code here, I'm just thinking out the broad strokes, and I want to keep things simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there... you have already added a Boolean column called `correct` in the schema for the `problem` model, so now you just need to access that as an attribute when updating an `Exam`. Som somewhere in your controller code, you would say:

```
ps=@exam_taken.problems
ps.each do |p|
   if answered_correctly(p)
        p.correct=true
        p.save
   end
end
# This assumes you have a method that checks correctness inside the binding where the
# above code is written

@exam_taken.save
```

If you are using Rails3, you would have to also declare the `correct` attribute as `attr_accessible` in your model.

And here's a free pro-tip: [Default scope is evil](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil) :)

Comment: if you use attr_accessible, wouldn't a clever user be able to mass-assign the correctness of his answer? why not handle this using toggle perhaps as a before_save within the model.

Comment: @saneshark - you're correct, I shouldn't have mentioned `attr_accessible`, that was my mistake. I won't edit my answer, it would make your comment hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @sameers and @saneshark! I'm using Rails4 so I'm not using attr_accessible for any of my models (I just noticed I'm not cleaning up my parameters for this controller, but...I'll be getting to that later). I'm answering questions one by one so I'm building my problem like so: 'problem = @exam.problems.where(fact_id: @answered)' When I check this in the console I am grabbing the right Problem from the database, but when I try to set 'problem.correct=true' I get a no method error: 'NoMethodError: undefined method `correct'' How should I be dealing with this?

Comment: A scope in Rails, like `@exam.problems.where(fact_id: @answered)` doesn't return an ActiveRecord object - it returns an ActiveRelation. An ActiveRelation could represent multiple objects (in your query above, there's no guarantee that there's only one `Problem` record that matches its conditions.) So you have to take the additional step of using the :[] method on the ActiveRelation - `problem[0].correct`.